# Android Studio - Shared Preferences and write speed

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm wondering if there is a speed at which shared preferences doesn't work correctly. I run the following code and have some weird issues.

```
1st run, 5 of 5 items show up in Set<>
2nd run, 4 of 5 items show up in Set<>
3rd run, 3 of 5 items show up in Set<>

public void addRemoteFacility(String newFacility){

   Set<String> facilityList = getRemoteFacilityList();

   editor.remove(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST);
   editor.commit();

   if(facilityList.size() == 0){

   facilityList.add(newFacility);
   editor.putStringSet(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST, facilityList);

   }
   else{

       if(!facilityList.contains(newFacility)){
           facilityList.add(newFacility);
           editor.putStringSet(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST, facilityList);
        }
   }
   editor.commit();
}

public Set<String> getRemoteFacilityList(){
    return sharedPref.getStringSet(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST, defaultSet);
}
```

In my main activity I'm trying the below

```
mPref = new PreferenceUtils(this);
    
mPref.addRemoteFacility("fFacility 0");
mPref.addRemoteFacility("aFacility 1");
mPref.addRemoteFacility("cFacility 2");
mPref.addRemoteFacility("eFacility 3");
mPref.addRemoteFacility("eFacility 4");
```

However, after main, when I call getRemoteFacilitiesList() every time I run my main activity, one less element shows up each time I check after this is run. I start off getting all 5 elements, so it's just weird it keeps removing 1 by one each time the code is run. I'm not expecting elements to be added this quickly, but am wondering why they are being removed in such an odd fashion.

Thanks for any help in the diagnosis.

EDIT** I'm guessing this may have something to do with commit() and apply() being asynchronous. Also, I should use apply() instead of commit() for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remodeled my code and everything works great now. The major change I made was moving the lines of code that used the editor to remove the key then commit this change before checking if I needed to.

1. Added a boolean to determine if I needed to make any changes
2. Only applying changes if a commit was successful

All in all, more lines of code, but there are less calls to commit() when they aren't necessary. Using apply for final call since I don't require a success or failure result. My only problem now is that it could be bad if I do successfully commit to removing my list, and apply not working properly... which would leave me with an empty list.

Below is my new code:

```
public void addRemoteFacility(String newFacility){
    
    boolean listUpdateRequired = false;
    Set<String> facilityList = getRemoteFacilityList();

    if(facilityList.size() == 0){
        facilityList.add(newFacility);
        listUpdateRequired = true;
    }
    else{
        if(!facilityList.contains(newFacility)){
            facilityList.add(newFacility);
            listUpdateRequired = true;
        }
    }

    // Item needs to be added to list
    if(listUpdateRequired){

        // Remove Current List
        editor.remove(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST);
        boolean removalResult = editor.commit();

        if(removalResult){
            editor.putStringSet(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST, facilityList);
            editor.apply();
        }
        else{
            Log.e("preferences", "failed to remove list, not applying changes");
        }
    }
}

public Set<String> getRemoteFacilityList(){
    return sharedPref.getStringSet(REMOTE_FACILITY_LIST, defaultSet);
}
```